# I'm confused about how order changes the probability in this specific basic combinatorics question...

Tags: probability, combinatorics

THE QUESTION: A bag contains seven white and five black discs. Three discs are chosen from the bag. Find the probability that all three discs are black, if the discs are chosen without replacement.

I understand that the answer is $_5C_3/\,_{12}C_3$, but why doesn't $5/12 \times 4/11 \times 3/10$ work? If all three disks are black, the first needs to be black $(5/12)$ and the second $(4/11)$ and so on. If anyone can explain why the latter method doesn't work in a manner simple enough for a pre-calculus high school student to understand, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: These two expressions seem to be equal.

Answer (score 1):

When all chosen balls are of the same color, the two expressions will give the same result.

The problem comes if you are asked, say, the probability that $2$ are black and one is white.

Since one particular order has not been specified,

$\Large\frac{\binom52\binom71}{\binom{12}3}$ will give the correct answer, but if you want to use direct multiplication, $\frac5{12}\frac4{11}\frac7{10}$ only gives the probabilty of getting $BBW$ in **that particular order**, and needs to be multiplied by $3$, because the discs can come out in $\binom32$ ways as $BBW, BWB, WBB$

Comment: Thank you, sorry I think I confused myself with my original question.

Comment: Glad to be of help ! $\;\;$ :)